# ¿Como puedo optimizar un par de imágenes para utilizar en un CardView, sin que esto haga tan lenta la Activity?

Tags: android, android-imageview, cardview

Estoy montando unas imágenes en un CardView, llamadas directamente desde la Activity Java, el problema es que al abrir la nueva Activity que contiene las imágenes,se congela y tarda en cargar. Así estoy llamando las ImageView:

```
//...
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.logo_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
//...
```

Comment: De que tamaño es la imagen logo?

Comment: Cárgalas de manera Asíncrona con Glide o Picasso e Intenta guardar el Logo con el tamaño mínimo utilizando una herramienta de compresión de imágenes online y utiliza un recyclerview en conjunto con el CarView para mayor optimizacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que tus imágenes son de tamaño considerable y que su manejo en memoria provoca un gran consumo de recursos, sin duda debes optimizarlas o usar otro método para cargar la imagen, el cual la optimice y cargue en la vista.

¿Como lograr que tu imagen sea ligera?, bueno puedes trabajar con la **[compresión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compresi%C3%B3n_de_imagen)** en bytes.

Aquí un tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/ticvalcarcel/optimizacion-de-imagenes-para-internet/tamano-y-peso-de-las-imagenes

El SDK de Android tiene una forma de optimizar el cargado de imágenes, que implica el tomar un formato de imagen mas pequeno por medio de la clase **[BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options))**:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

---

Otras opciones para cargar las imágenes son el uso de dos librerías que pueden ayudar, **[PICASSO](https://geekytheory.com/gestion-de-imagenes-en-android-con-picasso)** y [**GLIDE**](http://www.androidchile.org/blog/2016/05/carga-de-imagenes-con-glide/) , cuya implementación es sencilla y muy similar. Sin embargo hay que considerar siempre la optimización de las imágenes.

Ejemplo **[PICASSO](https://geekytheory.com/gestion-de-imagenes-en-android-con-picasso)**

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.logo_image);
//imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.logo).into(imageView);
```

Ejemplo [**GLIDE**](http://www.androidchile.org/blog/2016/05/carga-de-imagenes-con-glide/) :

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.logo_image);
//imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.logo).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

si es asi mejor utiliza la libreria piccaso https://desarrollador-android.com/librerias/square/picasso/

```
    Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/imagen.png").fit().into(imageView);
```

**fit():** para que la imagen se adapte al tamaño del contenedor
o sutituye **.fit()** por **.resize(50, 50)**

**resize:** redimensionará la imagen al tamaño de pixeles que tu le asignes(No es muy recomendable por los diferentes tipos de resolucion de pantallas, pero es mas rápido que fit())