# OutOfMemory Exceptio - Android APP con ImageViews a modo de "Galería"

Tags: android, recyclerview, fragment, android-imageview, out-of-memory-error

[image: La foto es .net , yo hice lo mismo para Android con imageviews & recyclerview pero no tengo fotos por aquí.]

La foto es .net , yo hice lo mismo para Android con imageviews & recyclerview pero no tengo fotos...
Lo dicho, conseguí que esto fuera tal cual en mi app android, las fotos de la galeria multimedia local van asociadas a un folder en el que meto las fotos capturadas por la cámara, osea bitmaps, para la cámara utilizo la libreria magicalcamera.
Los archivos compartidos son fotos que se suben a una base de datos mysql ( pero no hacer caso a esto)
El caso, **la app trabaja con fragments.**
Y hago fotos, llegan al folder, se muestran tal cual la foto, y todo perfecto, pero cuando la calidad de estas fotos es normalita, y hago varias, pues peta con esta dichosa excepción... He investigado sobre el tema pero no consigo solucionarlo... 
La libreria *magical camera tiene una variable que dice del 1 al 100* la calidad de la foto en un % final de resolución (o eso creo, pero vamos me habéis entendido).
***Las "miniaturas" me da igual la resolución que tengan, pero que se vea algo, pero lo que es la imagen final no puede bajar la calidad... Lo digo porque he probado a poner 40 de calidad, y si en vez de mostrarme 6 fotos me muestra 20, pero sigue petando y la calidad me baja...*** 
He intentado algo poniendo las "miniaturas" con valor null cuando pasas por encima de ellas con el scroll, de manera que no muestran nada, solamente que hay una foto ahí... Pero aún así no funciona.
**Quiero vuestra opinión, tiene esto una solución real, o tengo que buscar una alternativa como Glide/Picasso... Me llevó bastante tiempo hacer esto y me da pena tener que desechar el trabajo y tener que usar una librería... Y bueno, si esta librería me promete que no voy a tener fallo pues tendré que usarla...** 
*También tengo que decir que se me olvidó, que las miniaturas son image button, no se si es un dato que sea importante pero vamos lo digo por si las moscas... Cuando pulsas en las imagenes no las tiene que abrir ni nada, simplemente mantener un foco en ella hasta que pulsas el botón de la flechita y las envía a la base de datos.*
Antes de despedirme, **quiero pedir perdón por expresarme tan MAL,** si no has entendido algo preguntame e intenta leerlo de nuevo por favor, me sería de mucha ayuda cualquier información sobre el tema! ^^

---

Vale, os comento, estoy intentando hacerlo con glide pero no consigo sacar una solución, me saca problemas de contextos en mi clase donde utilizo Glide y ya llevo un rato intentando y no soluciono nada ...

```
public class Fotos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Fotos.ViewHolder> {


private List<ImageItem> fotosLista;
private ImageView image;


public Fotos(List<ImageItem> fotosLista) {

    this.fotosLista = fotosLista;

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public View view;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);


    ViewHolder tvh = new ViewHolder(itemView);

    return tvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {


    ImageItem item = fotosLista.get(pos);
    image = viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);


    Glide.with(//AQUÍ DEBERÍA IR THIS, GETCONTEXT, GETACTIVITY, O ALGO DEL ESTILO PERO ME DA FALLO SIEMPRE... Y NO SE COMO DECLARARLO).load(item)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(image);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != fotosLista ? fotosLista.size() : 0);
}
```

}

**Ir a la parte donde utilizo Glide para ver el fallo, comente una cosa donde es...
Probé varias cosas declarando un contexto por mi cuenta pero me da fallo
Y no puedo usar this, o get context o algo del estilo porque la clase extiende de RecyclerView.Adapter ...**

*Pongo la clase principal del fragmento donde voy a mostrar todo, que va relacionado con el error de arriba, con el tema del context again*

```
public class Archivos extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView recView;
private RecyclerView recView2;

private List<ImageItem> fotosList;
private ArrayList<Select> Array;
private ImageButton botonSubida;
ArrayList<ImageItem> item = new ArrayList<>();


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archivos, container, false);



    recView = view.findViewById(R.id.ViewIzquierda);
    //recView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.ViewDerecha);
    botonSubida = view.findViewById(R.id.botontransferenciafotos);
    obtenerFotos();



    return view;
}

public void obtenerFotos() {
    fotosList = new ArrayList<>();
    // list of file paths
    File[] listFile;

    File file = new File("storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myDirectoryName");


    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        if (file.exists()) {

            listFile = file.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {




                ImageItem imageModel = new ImageItem();

                item.add(imageModel);


                recView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(recView.getContext(), 3));
                recView.setHasFixedSize(true);






                RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;



                adapter = new Fotos(//AQUI ESTA EL ERROR- EN el Archivos.this (Y es lo que debería ir ahí para que todo funcionase) //Archivos.this , item);

                recView.setAdapter(adapter);




            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En efecto hay forma de evitar el OutOfMemory con Glide. Pero hay más factores que implican dicho consumo de memoria masiva. Si crees que definiste una buena arquitectura para tu código (limpias la mayor cantidad de objetos, listeners al no utilizarlos) y utilizaste los mejores widgets y patrones para optimización tal como los RecyclerViews, primero que todo, agrega Glide a tu adapter y comparte el adapter del RecyclerView que utilizaste para hacer el Grid en esa pantalla. Para enseñarte un par de trucos de optimización con Glide adaptado al RecyclerView. Saludos.

Comment: Pues el martes me pongo al tajo, a ver si pillo información de glide que me mole y pueda usarlo bien... En cuanto tenga algo para poder enseñar lo comparto por aquí ! Muchas gracias por responder =)

Comment: Notificame aqui mismo con una mención en cuanto compartas tu adapter para ayudarte.

Comment: Eso haré, mil gracias :)

Comment: Una parte importante de optimizar tu aplicación es optimizar principalmente las imágenes. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106489/como-puedo-optimizar-un-par-de-im%C3%A1genes-para-utilizar-en-un-cardview-sin-que-e/106688#106688 eso puede ser la causa principal, pero también la forma como realizaste tu aplicación, puede ser que estes dejando instancias en memoria. @Chuflitas

Comment: Se trata de las imágenes, cuando les pongo ponga calidad me muestra muchas ... Lo trataré de solucionar con glide , os cuento mañana

Comment: Voy a añadir una respuesta a la pregunta con toda la info para que le eches un ojo, que tengo problema de contextos para usar glide @Andrespengineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya se ha comentado [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) es una librería potente para la carga de imágenes y performance dentro de un App.

[Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) en su builder pattern, utiliza Contextos y cada uno de ellos de adapta a quien lo maneja.

Por ejemplo al utilizar el `getContext()` de un `Fragment`, [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) se suscribe a los eventos del ciclo de vida de dicho `Fragment` y tan pronto como se disparan sus eventos del ciclo de vida, digamos que se detiene, cualquier solicitud pendiente se debe pausar; y cuando se destruye, se borran todas las solicitudes pendientes. Esto significa que la descarga de la imagen se detendrá a mitad de camino y no se usarán más recursos por ese `Fragment` destruido. Por otro lado si se utiliza con `getActivity()`, Glide se suscribe a los eventos del ciclo de vida de la `Activity` y sucede lo mismo que anterior, pero solo cuando la `Activity` se detiene o se destruye.

Bien, ahora digamos que quieres almacenar una gran cantidad de imagen en cache, como por ejemplo; en las redes sociales, almacenar un numero de imágenes de perfil de tus amigos (aquellas que se obtienen desde el servidor, y se guardan en cache para cuando se interrumpa la conexión a Internet), como esos datos quieres que estén seguros para cuando se interrumpa la conexión y seguir teniendo la misma persistencia. Dichas imágenes que por lo general son thumbnails y no consumen mucha memoria,  deben ser cargadas con el `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` esto, como no tiene un ciclo de vida tan corto como los `Activity` y los `Fragment`, hara que las imágenes se guarden en cache sin interrupciones a las descargas, asegurando que estarán ahí para usarse y que luego periódicamente se ira limpiando y enviada al `Garbage Collector`.

Ahora bien, en tu caso, como tu `Adapter` puede estar sujeto a varios contextos y los elementos son parte del `ViewHolder`. En teoría no sabes cual contexto utilizar y una de las formas mas comunes es enviar el contexto en el constructor del `Adapter`. Pero esto te puede traer problemas futuros.

La **solucion** es la siguiente:

Primero que todo arreglar tu `ViewHolder`.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    }
}
```

y tu `onBinViewHolder` deberia quedar asi:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {

    ImageItem item = fotosLista.get(pos);

    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext()).load(item)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(viewHolder.imageView);
}
```

El problema que tienes en tu `ViewHolder`, es que estas buscando una referencia cada vez que el `onBind` se dispara. Realmente solo debes realizar tareas que cambien el contenido o las vistas de cierta forma en el `onBind`. En este caso esta bien que el item se obtenga ahi, ya que por cada elemento, su item puede ser diferente. Sin embargo, obtener la referencia de una vista, agregar algún estilo, animacion, color, listeners, digase `onClick`, `onTouch`, etc... que sea el mismo para todos los elementos, deberia ir en la clase del `ViewHolder`, porque no tiene sentido agregarle la misma propiedad o referencia a un elemento que nunca va a cambiar en el `onBind` que siempre se va a disparar, lo recomendable es que se agregue dichos elementos en la clase del `Holder` por buena practica.

En teoria, esto resolveria tu problema. Glide con thumbnails, pero que pasa si aun te sigue dando problemas. Puedes utilizar unos trucos que te ayudaran a evitar **OOM** en caso de que siga sucediendote:

- Limpiar las vistas cada vez que se reciclan: como [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) almacena internamente las imágenes en la cache, agregando su `DiskCacheStrategy`. Esto no hace que la vista al reciclarse, por igual se recicle su referencia dicha imagen en la cache, por lo que nunca esa referencia se borrara de la cache al menos que destruyas la aplicacion. Dicho esto, puedes utilizar un truco para limpiar la cache manualmente de la siguiente manera:

Creas el método, para obtener todos los `ImageViews` del holder reciclado:

```
private void clearAllImageViews(ViewGroup viewGroup){
     for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
          View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
          if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
             clearAllImageViews((ViewGroup)view);
          else if (view instanceof ImageView){
              if(((Activity)viewGroup.getContext()) != null && !((Activity)viewGroup.getContext()).isDestroyed())
                  Glide.with(viewGroup.getContext()).clear((ImageView)view);
                }
           }
   }
```

Y sobreescribes el metodo de tu adapter que recicla la vista:

```
@Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        clearAllImageViews((ViewGroup)holder.itemView);
    }
```

La idea es buscar todas las `ImageView` que hay en tu holder reciclado con el itemView y limpiarlos manualmente con Glide. Saludos.

Comment: Chapó! Muchísimas gracias ^^ He entendido todo genial, yo que siempre me lío con los context xD