# Duplicado de imágenes en un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

tengo un pequeño problema al cargar unas imágenes en un `RecyclerView`, lo que pasa es que al cargar los datos desde **Firebase** las imágenes se duplican o se cambian de posición al hacer `Scroll`.

Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

**Imagen cargada correctamente:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen duplicada tras hacer scroll:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

**Clase que recibe las imágenes desde Firebase y las pasa al adaptador:**

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            try{
                MensajeRecibir m = dataSnapshot.getValue(MensajeRecibir.class);
                String tipo = m.getType_mensaje();
                adapter.addMensaje(m);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Clase Adaptador que inserta las imágenes en el listview:**

```
public class AdapterMensajes extends RecyclerView.Adapter <HolderMensaje> {
private List<MensajeRecibir> listMensaje = new ArrayList<>();
private Context c;
private LinearLayout layoutBG;
private Context context;
private File localFile = null;

public AdapterMensajes(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void addMensaje(MensajeRecibir m){
    listMensaje.add(m);
    notifyItemInserted(listMensaje.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public HolderMensaje onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.card_view_mensajes,parent,false);
    layoutBG = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.mensajeBG);

    return new HolderMensaje(v) ;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HolderMensaje holder, int position) {
    holder.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.getMensaje().setText(listMensaje.get(position).getMensaje());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.getCardview().getLayoutParams();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams fl = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)holder.getLayoutBG().getLayoutParams();
    String name = getPreferences("name_usuario");
    if (listMensaje.get(position).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
        if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(c).load(listMensaje.get(position).getUrlFoto()).into(holder.getFotoMensaje());
        }else if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_pdf);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }else{
        if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(c).load(listMensaje.get(position).getUrlFoto()).into(holder.getFotoMensaje());
        }else if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_pdf);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Downloadfile(listMensaje.get(position).getUrlFoto());
        }else if (listMensaje.get(position).getType_mensaje().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            holder.getLayoutBG().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg);
            fl.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
            holder.getFotoMensaje().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.getMensaje().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    holder.getCardview().setLayoutParams(rl);
    holder.getLayoutBG().setLayoutParams(fl);

    long codigohora= listMensaje.get(position).getHora();
    Date d =new Date(codigohora);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
    holder.getHora().setText(sdf.format(d));
} 

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listMensaje.size();
}

public String getPreferences(String valor){
    Context context = c;
    SharedPreferences sharedPre = context.getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dato = sharedPre.getString(valor,"No hay dato");
    return dato;
}

public void Downloadfile(String url){
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference pathReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("Imagen","jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"PDF guardado en: "+localFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Error al descargar el PDF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: primero felicitarte por la app, se ve rre bien, segundo, te fijaste en tu database si se estan duplicando las keys de esa foto ? puedes poner el codigo donde cargas esas imagenes en el listview?

Comment: Gracias compañero, y ps si ya me fije y cada key es diferente, el problema es que se cargan en donde no debe ser y luego vuelve y se corrige, todo esto cada vez que hago scroll. Por cierto, ya actualice el código.

Comment: Revisa [Esta respuesta que hice para un problema parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166062/al-hacer-scroll-en-el-recycler-view-se-cambian-de-posici%C3%B3n-las-urls/166382#166382) el problema puede ser ese descrito en la respuesta. Si no es ese, entonces, revisa si asignaste debidamente un LayoutManager para el RecyclerView. Tambien el problema puede ser si estas cambiando esas propiedades de la vista con los LayoutParams. Tienes que reiniciar el estado de la vista en el metodo sobreescrito del RecyclerView llamado onViewRecycled.

Comment: Debes volver holder.getFotoImage() a su estado original, es decir, ponerle null al source de la foto. Ya que estas utilizando Glide, [revisa esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160344/outofmemory-exceptio-android-app-con-imageviews-a-modo-de-galer%C3%ADa/160863#160863) para limpiar las imágenes de las vistas que se han reciclado. Esto con el fin de evitar Out of Memory si cargas muchas imagenes en el RecyclerView con Glide. La vista se recicla al hacer scroll pero no el source. Déjame saber si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Exactamente me pasa lo que dice en la pregunta 1 que acabas de comentar, pero creo que la solución más probable podría ser la de limpiar el estado del source. Veré como me va.

Comment: En la parte en la que creas el método para limpiar las imágenes con Glide, me da error el `.clear`, es lo único.

Comment: @RosyecParrado revisa que estas utilizando la ultima version de Glide.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Tengo la versión 3.7.0 es la ultima no? Ps lo del `clear` lo solucione con `Glide.clear((ImageView)view);` pero pasa que al volver hacer scroll ahora si sale la imagen en donde debe ser pero se quita cada vez que subo y bajo y tiene que volver glide a descargarla.

Comment: El reciclado del recyclerview funciona con la propiedad ItemViewCacheSize. Normalmente esto se calcula previamente con el tamaño de elementos que tienes asignado en tu adapter. Por ejemplo, si tengo una lista de 100 imagenes que quiero cargarla y ya de antemano se que mi app puede soportar 20 antes de que explote. Entonces defino un itemviewcachesize de 20 para que despues que haga scroll y cargue la 21, empiece a reciclar la mas antigua que se cargo. Asi hago que esas 20 viejas se tengan que descargar nuevamente ya que se deben de eliminar obligatoriamente para liberar espacio.

Comment: Para ti que el problema es que no se carga tu imagen en la posición correcta, en el reciclado, intenta volver el imageview source a null. Con .setImageDrawable(null); al imageview del holder. Lo anterior, es por si en un futuro te causa OutOfMemoryException al cargar las imagenes con Glide.

Comment: Mmm ya, ps parece que si funciona solo que si hago el scroll rápido, en cada imagen por parte del usuario quien envía, en vez de verse la foto se pone la imagen pdf pero rápidamente se reemplaza por la foto, que sera? Ya empiezo a sospechar que si puede ser algo con los if y else pero no lo encuentro.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Creo que ya lo solucione compañero, resulta que la imagen del **PDF** la estaba poniendo como **Background** y no como una imagen que se carga en si, ahora si ya todo funciono. Muchas gracias por tú ayuda hermano, enserio fue muy útil también lo del limpiar la imagen con Glide. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, si quieres puedes postear tu solucion y automarcala como aceptada, de paso te dejare un voto positivo. Tambien me ayudarias votando por mis respuestas (en enlace azul) que te deje en los comentarios. Buena suerte.

Comment: Claro hermano, de una. Nuevamente Gracias.