# Por que mi actividad se lagea en Android Studio?

Tags: android, imagen

En mi proyecto tengo un **recycler view** el cual me empezó a **tildar** la aplicación desde el momento en el que puse las imágenes en los **ImageView**.

Me gustaría que alguien me pueda señalar la **causa** de la ralentización (**lag**) y como solucionarla porque es **algo molesto**.

**Aclaración:** La aplicación **se puede usar** tranquilamente, solo que va un poco **retardada** (y es un efecto bastante **notorio**) cuando estoy en esta actividad. **En las demás no hay ningún problema**

**Adjunto foto del recycler de mi actividad:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código XML de las imágenes del recycler:**

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_resultados"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>
```

**Adjunto el código JAVA que llena el Recycler**

```
public void llenarRecyclerResultados(){
    array_model_recycler_resultados.add(new model_recycler_resultados("Jorge 
    Hernandez","Lacroze 5051",R.drawable.a));

    array_model_recycler_resultados.add(new model_recycler_resultados
    ("Esteban Quito","Boulevard 2020",R.drawable.b));

    array_model_recycler_resultados.add(new 
    model_recycler_resultados("Monica Dellar","Alvear 4241",
    R.drawable.f));

    array_model_recycler_resultados.add(new 
    model_recycler_resultados("Lionel Messi","San Juan 4312",
    R.drawable.c));
}
```

**Adjunto una de las imágenes por si se quiere descargar:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por leer y feliz año nuevo a todos!

Comment: El problema es que las imagenes que usas son de mucha resolucion, al usar un ImageView las imagenes se cargan a memoria y luego se colocan en los imageview (al usar tanta memoria tu aplicacion se vera afectada), para evitar estos problemas te recomiendo que redimensiones y les bajes el peso innecesario a tus imagenes o uses una libreria que se encargue de hacer esto como glide(https://github.com/bumptech/glide) o fresco (https://frescolib.org/)

Comment: Hola Junior, muchisimas gracias por comentar. A que te referis cuando decís que las imágenes se cargan a memoria?. Otra pregunta: Redimensionar o bajar el peso de una imágen no hará que estas pierdan calidad?. Ahora mismo estoy investigando esa librería para ver si puedo utilizarla a mi favor.

Comment: Problema de memoria, sobretodo si estás cargando las imágenes con su tamaño original. Debes convertir tus imágenes a `thumbnails` para las visualizaciones en miniatura y solo cargar la imagen original cuando vayas a visualizarla si es el caso, pero me imagino que solo quieres mostrarlas en miniatura. La librería de Glide te permite convertirlas a Thumbnails. También puedes limpiar la memoria en el recyclado de las vistas `onViewRecycled` buscas los imageViews y los limpias con Glide. [Puedes ver más aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/160863/38154) y dejarme un voto si te funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Andres, en serio que estoy muy agradecido por tu respuesta pero, podrías detallar mejor lo que dices? Para mi hay muchas cosas nuevas en muy poco texto. No entiendo mucho a que te referis cuando decis que debería cargar la imágen solo cuando vaya a visualizarla. En mi caso las estoy visualizando en un recycler, por lo que eso no me quedó claro. Luego me dices de limpiar la memoria en el reciclado de las vistas. Eso que significa especificamente y para que es? Gracias de nuevo hermano!

Comment: Busca la libreria Glide o Picasso para cargar las imagenes, eso va a solucionar tu problema

Comment: Gracias Gastón por la ayuda y a todos los demás también. Ya pude solucionar el problema efectivamente y ya no tengo lag. Muchas gracias en serio!

Comment: di como lo solucionaste

Comment: Armen deberías empezar a leer las publicaciones. Arriba están las respuestas. Solamente hice uso de la libreria Glide para importar imágenes desde urls