# Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError en MainActivity - Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory-error

durante el desarrollo de mi app me percate que tiene un error especifico. Este se presenta especialmente en los dispositivos con Android 7. Pero supongo que es mas por las especificaciones de hardware del dispositivo que la version de Android.

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 37632012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 24MB until OOM**

El error completo es el siguiente:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
08-10 15:56:35.181 2453-2453/com.example.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myApp, PID: 2453
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 37632012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 24MB until OOM**
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.devsyf.trippmi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:212)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Me apunta al

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

En esa layout si tengo algunas cosas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layoutPlaces"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <include layout="@layout/content_barra_busqueda"></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivListaCombis"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/rl_combis"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLugares"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/catedral_morelia"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

     </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <include layout="@layout/menu_layout"></include>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

A que creen que se deba? Muchas gracias a todos :)

Comment: El problema es que estas utilizando muchas imagenes pesadas  en resolución y no las estas reciclando o no estas definiendo los drawables para diferentes dispositivos. ¿De casualidad estas creando o decodificando algún bitmap en código?.

Comment: Pero no utilizo demasiadas imágenes, son pocas. Pero si, tienes razón, no las tengo especificadas según la resolución. Estoy utilizando la librería de showcaseView (Esa que se utiliza para que se inicie un tutorial al inicio de la app). Según yo es el único bitmap.

Comment: Igual si tienen un tutorial que consideren bueno para la especificación de imágenes según su resolución, estaría perfecto. Aun soy muy nuevo en esto de Android.

Comment: Intenta utilizar lo que te ofrece Android Studio, [mira esta respuesta de SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021901/5280677). Si el problema continua, intenta bajar las resoluciones de las imagenes que utilizas o intenta utilizar librerias como [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para cargar las imágenes en vez de cargarla directamente en el `axml` con `src`.

Comment: @AlanOliver en realidad supones bien, de hecho tratar de alojar 37MB de una imagen, imagina si son varias. Revisa esta pregunta en el sitio que te da tips para optimizar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106489/como-puedo-optimizar-un-par-de-im%C3%A1genes-para-utilizar-en-un-cardview-sin-que-e/106688#106688

Comment: Es muy comun que cuando usas bitmpas tengas este tipo de errores por que no puede alojarlo en la memoria , te sugiero que leas un poco esto , esta en ingles pero seguro te ayuda https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios. @Andres, tenias razon. "Elimine" temporalmente las imagenes que presentaba en el MainActivity asi como el tutorial del inicio de ShowCaseView y el error desaparecio. 

Gracias por los links, los vere de inmediato. :D